# Non-swinging Foucault's pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, oscillators, precession

If there is a stationary pendulum, say at the North pole, neglecting torsion, etc. will it seem like spinning around its axis from the reference frame fixed to the Earth's surface. If so, will it still hold at any arbitrary point on the surface, except for maybe the Equator?

Answer (score 0):

A body suspended without torque at the North Pole would have a constant angular momentum and (assuming the vertical axis is one of its principal axes) a constant angular velocity in the space frame.  This would mean that if it was initially rotating with the Earth when it was released, it would keep rotating at the same angular velocity as the Earth — one rotation per day.  From the perspective of the Earth's frame, it would therefore remain at rest if it was released from rest.

I believe the same logic will apply to a ball anywhere on Earth's surface:  if it is initially rotating with the Earth, and there is no net torque on the object, then it will continue to rotate with the Earth.  The only difference for points not at the poles is that the object will also be accelerating due to the Earth's revolution;  but this translational acceleration is independent of the angular acceleration, and we are assuming that there is no torque exerted on the object.